# Using optional facelet tag libraries

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a web application that uses optional modules. The modules are implemented as Web Fragment projects, their jars may or may not be deployed with the war depending on the build profile.

A module can contain it's own `module.taglib.xml` with a `http://company.com/module` namespace and some tags.

The war xhtml templates use module tags like this:

```
<ui:composition ... xmlns:mod="http://company.com/module">

<c:if test="#{moduleDeployed}">
    <mod:someTag />
</c:if>
```

Problems.

1. When the module is not deployed, the war pages work fine, but in ProjectStage.Development I get FacesMessage warnings:

   > Warning: This page calls for XML namespace
   >   http://company.com/module declared with prefix mod but no
   >   taglibrary exists for that namespace.
2. As far as I can see, JSF specification doesn't define what happens, when a template uses a nonexistent tag library. So with my current approach war pages can stop working after an upgrade or a switch to a different JSF implementation.

Questions.

1. Is there a (not very ugly) way to disable this specific warning?
2. Is there a better approach to using optional facelet tag libraries?

As of now I plan to disable the warning anyway I can: e.g. override Messages renderer and check message string if I have to. If the problem 2 manifests, make the build supply placeholder taglib.xml files for not deployed modules.

Comment: Why not make sure the 'optional' module is always present? Waaaaay easier than all these kinds of hacks.

Comment: For the purposes of the question that's a requirement. 1. Don't want to supply to a customer more than was ordered. 2. Dynamic binding stuff, e.g. CDI alternatives. 3. Enforcement of correctness of said dynamic binding stuff implementation.

Comment: Placeholder taglib isn't such a bad idea actually.

Comment: Placeholder taglib is a last resort for me, because we use Maven, and everything (profiled builds) has to work with m2e too.

Comment: It isn't a bad idea specifically because your build system currently already knows how to distinguish them. I'd consider that a "clean" solution then without the need to hack around in JSF API/impl. A completely different alternative would be to provide/specify include files as entry point, in combination with a custom resource handler, but that requires changes in templates, making them less clean.

Comment: @BalusC, what's a custom resource handler for? `ui:include`s work across web fragment boundaries as it is.

Comment: To check if it exists or not, otherwise you get resource not found errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though placeholder taglibs seemed like a pretty good solution, they also seemed harder to implement and maintain.

So in the end I went with filtering the messages. This is likely Mojarra specific: the message text, the fact that the iterator allows removal (this isn't forbidden by the spec, but it's not required either). It's known to work with Mojarra 2.2.8 to 2.2.13.

```
public class SuppressNoTaglibraryExistsFacesMessage implements SystemEventListener {
    private static final Pattern PTTRN_NO_TAGLIBRARY_EXISTS_FOR_NAMESPACE =
            Pattern.compile("Warning: This page calls for XML namespace \\S+ declared with "
            + "prefix \\S+ but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.");

    @Override
    public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) {
        Iterator<FacesMessage> messages = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessages();
        while (messages.hasNext()) {
            String messageSummary = messages.next().getSummary();
            if (PTTRN_NO_TAGLIBRARY_EXISTS_FOR_NAMESPACE.matcher(messageSummary).matches()) {
                messages.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isListenerForSource(Object source) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Bind the listener only in Development project stage.

```
public class SubscribeListenersAfterApplicationPostConstructListener
        implements SystemEventListener {
    @Override
    public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        Application application = (Application) event.getSource();
        if (ProjectStage.Development.equals(application.getProjectStage())) {
            application.subscribeToEvent(PostAddToViewEvent.class, UIViewRoot.class,
                    new SuppressNoTaglibraryExistsFacesMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isListenerForSource(Object source) {
        return source instanceof Application;
    }

}
```

And in faces-config.xml:

```
<system-event-listener>
    <system-event-listener-class><packages>.SubscribeListenersAfterApplicationPostConstructListener</system-event-listener-class>
    <system-event-class>javax.faces.event.PostConstructApplicationEvent</system-event-class>
</system-event-listener>
```

Comment: Definitely. Added a preface about that.